# Why native Russian series sound dubbed even in Russian? Almost unnatural

Tags: sound-effects, russian-cinema, cinema-sound

I have been watching a few Russian series lately. In some of them, when Russian actors and actresses speak,  the sound seems unnatural, almost dubbed. Or it does not blend in naturally with the surrounding sound environment?

For example,  in Catherine the Great, at 3:04:00 and other locations

I know in one of them (Master and Margarita), the director did not like the voice of the actor who played the devil, so he dubbed it by the voice of another. But here, I am talking about a whole series or movies? Is it the sound equipment? Or that the actors' voices are processed to give this effect? or delivered higher than the surrounded environment?

Comment: Can you explain what makes you think they are dubbed?

Comment: I feel like there is a slight asynchronization between video and sounds, that is especially noticeable when somebody is speaking. Might even be a problem of this particular video

Answer (score 3):

It's not just Russian thing. There is a western Europe type of cinema where the visual aesthetics are the most important part of movie. So important that time that would be needed to hide mics, do sound checks for certain scenes is cut out. Because you can always dub the movie later. And cheaper. Two mics on a stand instead of few hidden in bushes or a guy with a boom pole.

For example even before I watched that 3:04:00 scene I knew it will be an outdoor one. Imagine the amount of work it would require to get good quality sound for that whole scene. You would need few extra takes just for the sound alone.